# class.getResource definition

Tags: java

I am using getResources() on my splash java Class like this:

```
splashImage = 
   (new ImageIcon(Splash.class.getResource("/resources/splash.png"))).getImage();
```

Looking at the API on docs.oracle I see that getResources return is a URL. Why do I need it and what exactly does it return?

Comment: It's useful when you need to access resources within jar file.

Comment: Why is it a problem that it is an special procol URL? http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask